# HTML what happens if an ARIA attribute isn't preset

Tags: html

What happens if an ARIA attribute isn't preset? I.E, `<div role="ThisRoleDoesntExist"><h1>This is a simple site</h1><p>And here's it's simple paragraph</p></div>`

Comment: The universe implodes, so try and avoid that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing happens. It will act as though there is no role at all.